# unable to add ionic-platform-web-client

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

```
$ ionic add ionic-platform-web-client


Failed to find the bower component "ionic-platform-web-client".
Are you sure it exists? (CLI v1.7.12)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.2.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 
Node Version: v4.2.2
```

I tried the following command, didnt help as suggested in other stackoverflow Q&A.

```
 bower install --allow-root --save-dev ionic-platform-web-client
```

Same issue when i tried in mac as well. Attached both the error messages.

```
ionic add ios



Failed to find the bower component "ios".
Are you sure it exists? (CLI v1.7.12)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
ios-deploy version: 1.8.3 
ios-sim version: 5.0.4 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.2.4
Xcode version: Xcode 6.4 Build version 6E35b
```

Comment: same with my apple machine as well

Comment: Ok, i did add cordova add ios and the issue has been resolved. But not clear how it is related. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This below command may be solve your problem :-

**bower install --save-dev ionic-platform-web-client**

Comment: sweet jeebuss, yes!!

Comment: @N.Raval Why does this "fix it"?